# CSS display:block not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS and HTML to complete a contact form, but the boxes aren't displaying in a 'block' form (display:block)
HTML:

```
<section class="body">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

        <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
        <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
  width:576px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the .body?? is it a div??

Comment: try display:block !important; in css

Comment: *but the boxes aren't displaying in a block*: What boxes? What do you think `display:block` does?

Comment: your class already display:block by default as you never give it display:none; do you want to change none to block on some event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean input fields are not displaying as blocks. If so you need wrap your input fields in divs like that

```
<section class="body">
   <form method="post" action="index.php">
      <div>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Email</label>
         <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Message</label>
         <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
         <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
      </div>
      <div>
         <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"
            value="Submit">
      </div>
   </form>
</section>
```

and write this css code for divs

```
div, .body {
  width:576px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%
}
```

the result you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2e1fnxga/)

Comment: `!important;` should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your css:

```
input, textarea {
    display: block; 
}
```

This makes ALL input fields and text areas display block, so use classes if you only want certain ones to be display block.

Alternately, I create a .block {display: block;} class and add that to each input/textarea if you want field by field control.

Answer (score 0):

Place Your input and labels in separate div's

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bnnve0gg/)

```
 <section class="body">  
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<div> 
    <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
</div>
<div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
</div>
<div>
     <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
</div>
<div>   
        <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
        <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
</div>   
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>    
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your elements in ul and apply style

See a Working demo here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s0d6vx5b/)

```
 <section class="body">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <ul class="ul">
           <li>   
               <label>Name</label>
           </li> 
          <li>
                <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
          </li>
          <li>
                <label>Email</label>
          </li>
          <li>
                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
          </li>
          <li>
                 <label>Message</label>
          </li>
          <li>
                 <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
          </li>
          <li>
                 <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label></li>
          <li>
                 <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
         </li>
          <li>
                 <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
         </li>
</ul>
```